# SQL server data default

Tags: sql-server

Ola, estou criando uma tabela e preciso deixar a data de expiração como padrão a data 1990/01/01. alguem poderia me dar uma ajuda?

Abaixo o codigo que ja criei.

```
create table Coordenador (
    ID int NOT NULL identity(1,1)
    ,idlogin varchar(30) not null
    ,senha varchar(15) not null
    ,Nome varchar(30) not null
    ,Email varchar(100) not null
    ,Celular varchar(14) not null
    ,DtExpiracao date default getdate()
    ,constraint PK_Coordenador
        primary key (ID)
    ,constraint AK_login UNIQUE(idlogin)
    ,constraint AK_Email unique(email)
    ,constraint AK_Celular unique(celular)

);
go
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta adicionar `default` na coluna DtExpiracao com a data no formato YYYYMMDD ou no formato da linguagem definida para o banco, assim:

```
DtExpiracao datetime default ('19900101')
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que baste você alterar o valor que está sendo atribuído como *default*:

```
declare @dataDefault datetime
select @dataDefault = convert(datetime, '1990/01/01')

create table Coordenador (
    ID int NOT NULL identity(1,1)
    ,idlogin varchar(30) not null
    ,senha varchar(15) not null
    ,Nome varchar(30) not null
    ,Email varchar(100) not null
    ,Celular varchar(14) not null
    ,DtExpiracao datetime default @dataDefault 
    ,constraint PK_Coordenador
        primary key (ID)
    ,constraint AK_login UNIQUE(idlogin)
    ,constraint AK_Email unique(email)
    ,constraint AK_Celular unique(celular)
);
```